# Mathematical induction in recursively defined converging sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am familiar with the mathematical induction method followed to prove that sequences have a lower or upper bound, but I don't get exactly how and why they work. I am selecting a question from a real analysis book to help me understand this better.

[image]

[image]

I don't quite understand the highlighted part, do they use terms 1 and 2 to get an idea about the bound through mathematical induction and later give a formal proof and if so on what criteria are they selecting the bound? I find it hard to digest that just finding 2 terms can give you the lowest bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the lowest upper bound for $(y_n)$ is $3/2$, not $2$. If you wanted to, you could also use induction to show that $y_n < 1000000$ for all $n$. In practice you just need to find *some* upper bound. This is usually done by computing the first few terms of the sequence, making a guess, and then trying to prove it. Why did the author choose $2$ and not $1000000$? We can't know for sure, but most would agree that $2$ is a nicer number to work with.

Comment: Ohk, I see. Yeah, I agree the lowest upper bound (supremum) would obviously be 3/2 (the limit of the sequence when it is a bounded increasing one). Now I get that we just needed to find a bound to work with to prove that the sequence is bounded.